# Reuse options in _arguments for Zsh completion

Tags: zsh-completion

I have a python program that utilizes `action='append'` of python. For example, I can use the command like this

```
mod_db -i $HOME -i $PWD -i /usr/local foo bar
```

How can I use `_arguments` or anything else to implement the Zsh completion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found the answer by looking at the completion for gcc [here](https://www.apt-browse.org/browse/ubuntu/precise/main/i386/zsh/4.3.17-1ubuntu1/file/usr/share/zsh/functions/Completion/Unix/_gcc). The solution is to add a `*` before the command. For example,

```
_arguments -C \
     '*-i[a path]:path:_path_files -/' \
     ......
```